# Conditional statements act weirdly within my scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, web-scraping

I've written a python script using two conditional statements within a `for loop` to check whether the next page url is available in a certain webpage. If the link is available, the script is supposed to print that link. However, if there is no such link, it should execute the `else` block and print this line `No link is there`.

When I run my below script, It only prints the link (which is within `if` block) when available but when there is no such link then it never executes the `else` block and quits (no error is there either).

Btw, I wish to keep the `for loop` and make my script print the statement within `else` block. How can I do so?

This is the script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

keyword = ["coffee","uranium"] #the keyword uranium when gets passed to the function it is supposed to execute the else block
url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc={}&find_loc=San+Francisco"

def check_link(link,query):
    res = requests.get(link.format(query))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for link in soup.select(".pagination-links .next"):
        if link:
            print(link.get("href"))

        else:
            print("No link is there")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in keyword:
        check_link(url,item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's no match for the selector, `soup.select()` returns an empty list. There's nothing to loop over, so you never get to the `if`. It doesn't return a list containing any `None` elements.

You should test the length of the list that it returns instead:

```
links = soup.select(".pagination-links .next")
if links:
    for link in links:
        print(link.get("href"))
else:
    print("No link is there")
```